# How to delete sub folders and files if resides using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to delete all sub folders and files residing in the sub folder of specified path.

I am new to C# coding please help me.

Suppose I have the path: "C:\Files\aaa-426962\15-02-2013\index.html"

If I specify "C:\Files\aaa-426962" then all sub folders and files residing under "C:\Files\aaa-426962" should be deleted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`global::System.IO.Directory.Delete(@"C:\Files\aaa-426962", true);`